# Redirecting traffic using GeoIP and .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, geoip

I'm trying to redirect web traffic from Argentina to a certain page from our website, and all the other traffic to a different page, using GeoIP and .htaccess.

This is an example of what I'm trying to use (in this example, I'm using only two countries, Argentina and Colombia.)

```
GeoIPEnable On

# Redirect Colombia
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^CO$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsites.com.ar/index2.html [L]

# Redirect Argentina
#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^AR [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com.ar/index.html [L]
```

Thing is, it doesn't work.

I also tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} !^AR$
```

instead of declaring every single country I want to redirect, but didn't work, either.

Can anyone spot the problem?

Thanks in advance,

Ignacio

Comment: In your example the settings for Argentina are marked as comments. I would assume that this will not do anything...

Answer (score 1):

In your .htaccess, put following code 
This will redirect all traffic( outside of India) to https://newexample.abc.com

```
<IfModule mod_geoip.c>
            GeoIPEnable On
            RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} !^IN$
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newexample.abc.com/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: where i can get the country code list for `.htaccess` like should we use `^US$` or `^USA$`

Comment: @RajeevRanjanSharma: You could use this country code list https://www.iban.com/country-codes or this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 - always use the 2 letter "alpha-2" abbreviation

Answer (score 0):

did you try to do the equal the syntax used for Colombia ?

```
    # Redirect Argentina
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^AR$ 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com.ar/index.html [L]
```

```
I think [NC] is not necessary because GeoIP database is Uppercase (as I see on csv).

You can find more at http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/mod_geoip2/#Examples
```

Comment: where i can get the country code list for `.htaccess` like should we use `^US$` or `^USA$`

Comment: @RajeevRanjanSharma: You could use this country code list https://www.iban.com/country-codes or this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 - always use the 2 letter "alpha-2" abbreviation